# Issue with 3DES encryption - different ciphertext each time

Tags: c#, cryptography

I tried implementing 3DES in ECB mode in c#.

The problem is code below gives me **different ciphertext** each time I run it, even though I pass it same parameters as you can see - and I use **ECB** mode.

Can someone help what is wrong? The output must be same each time I run program below isn't it?

```
        public static byte[] SingleBlock3DES_ECB_Encrypt(byte [] plain, byte [] key)
        {
            if(plain.Length != 8)
                throw new Exception("Plain text length for single block should be 8 bytes");

            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

            // set the secret key for the tripleDES algorithm
            tdes.Key = key;

            // mode of operation. there are other 4 modes.
            // We choose ECB(Electronic code Book)
            tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

            // padding mode(if any extra byte added)
            tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

            // Set key size
            tdes.KeySize = 192;

            ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();

            // transform the specified region of bytes array to resultArray
            byte[] resultArray =  cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(plain, 0, plain.Length);

            // Release resources held by TripleDes Encryptor
            tdes.Clear();

            return resultArray;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] plain = new byte[8];
            byte[] key = new byte[24];

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                plain[i] = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
                key[i] = (byte) i;

            byte[] res = SingleBlock3DES_ECB_Encrypt(plain, key);

            string hex = BitConverter.ToString(res);
            Console.WriteLine(hex);
        }
```

So in simple words if I run this program multiple times I get different output each time. Clearly there must be some problem somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have written, if you remove `tdes.KeySize = 192` the code works. But what happens in truth is that when you

```
tdes.KeySize = 192;
```

the `key` is reset to a random value.

So you could move the

```
tdes.KeySize = 192;
```

BEFORE the

```
tdes.Key = key;
```

or simply remove it, because for 3DES the `KeySize` is fixed to 192.

Comment: Also most code I have seen with 3DES use TransformFinalBlock, can you explain why? Why not TransformBlock? e.g. this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413576/how-to-implement-triple-des-in-c-sharp-complete-example

Comment: @user200312 Because encryption algorithms are normally done in blocks of x bytes (8 bytes for 3DES). If you try to encrypt 5 bytes, the `TransformBlock` won't encrypt anything and will keep the 5 bytes for the next "round". If you try to encrypt 9 bytes, then `TransformBlock` will encrypt 8 bytes and keep the 9th byte for the next "round". So if you encrypt 9 bytes and then 7 bytes it will be equivalent to encrypting 8 + 8 bytes.

Comment: @user200312 The `TransformFinalBlock` tells the library that you are passing the final block, so even if there are too few bytes, the library will pad the bytes in some way (there are various padding algorithms, the `tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.SOMETHING`) and encrypt them

Comment: If I have 3DES ECB encryption of single block working fine, this means I can implement 3DES CBC MAC from it right? (I know library can do it too, just want to know if what I have is enough to implement 3DES CBC MAC too manually?) thanks

Comment: @user200312 Yes. The ECB is the starting "block" from which all the other chaining methods can be built.

Comment: Thanks but I still don't get why the code I linked above uses single TransformFinalBlock , instead of consecutive TransformBlocks?

Comment: @user200312 `if(plain.Length != 8)` the accepted block length is 8, so there is no difference.

Comment: Yes but here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413576/how-to-implement-triple-des-in-c-sharp-complete-example, they use just one call to TransformFinalBlock even with arbitrary length plain texts instead of many times calling TranformBlock and in the end TransformFinalBlock

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103930/discussion-between-xanatos-and-user200312).

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. By some miracle, when I remove this

```
  tdes.KeySize = 192;
```

from code, it works.