# DES Encryption keys

Tags: security, encryption, des, symmetric-key

I was reading about DES Triple Encryption,and I found a lot of diffrent combinations of the 3 keys , for example there's : using k1 - k2 - k3 , as there's k1- k2 - k1 , ... 
My Question is , what is the diffrence between these combinations? and which one is advisable (most used) ?

Comment: 3DES should not be used in new work, it is superseded by AES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How many keys does Triple DES encryption need?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39446834/how-many-keys-does-triple-des-encryption-need?rq=1) should provide depth to the following answer:

Using three distinct keys is the best way to go.  In fact, it's the only option for the US Government (and US Government contractors):

> 3.2.1.2 Triple Data Encryption Algorithm (TDEA)
>
> The Triple Data Encryption Algorithm (TDEA), also known as Triple DES, uses the DES
>   cryptographic engine to transform data in three operations. TDEA is
>   specified in SP 800-67.
>
> TDEA encrypts data in blocks of 64 bits, using three keys that define
>   a key bundle. The use of  TDEA  using  three  distinctly  different 
>   (i.e.,  mathematically  independent)  keys  is approved and  is 
>   commonly  known  as  three-key  TDEA  (also  referred  to  as  3TDEA 
>   or  3TDES).
>
> **Other  variations  of  TDEA,  where  two  or  three  of  the  keys 
>   are  identical,  are no  longer  approved** for applying cryptographic
>   protection  because of increased computing power or weaknesses in the
>   algorithm.

(Emphasis mine).  Source: http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/drafts/800-175/sp800-175b_draft.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the reference, it helped me a lot