# Save encrypted connection string in app.config dynamically

Tags: c#

I used connection string in app.config file in c#. I want to change connection string dynamically. I used a form to change the connection string. i want when i change server configuration and click to save it the connection string encrypted. i use a text box to encrypted password field when text changed.i use following code to encrypted connection string. it save the connection string encrypted but my software not connect the database for the encryption. It shows no valid password. How to Solve this problem?
[image]

```html
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DBPath = cbodbsource.Text + txtdbname.Text;
            //Set connection string
            string connectionString = string.Format("Provider={0};Data Source={1};Jet OLEDB:Database Password={2};", cboProvider.Text, DBPath, txtdbpassword.Text);
            try
            {
                OledbHelper helper = new OledbHelper(connectionString);
                if (helper.IsConnection)
                {
                    AppSetting setting = new AppSetting();
                    setting.SaveConnectionString("con", connectionString);
                    MessageBox.Show("Your connection string has been successfully saved.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

```html
string Encrypt(string source, string key)
        {
            using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDESCryptoService = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashMD5Provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
                {
                    byte[] byteHash = hashMD5Provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
                    tripleDESCryptoService.Key = byteHash;
                    tripleDESCryptoService.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
                    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);
                    return Convert.ToBase64String(tripleDESCryptoService.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length));
                }
            }
        }
```

I have used text_Changed Event Code. Here is it

```html
private void txtdbpassword_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtEncrypt.Text = this.Encrypt(txtdbpassword.Text, "myconstring");
}
```

Comment: Where do you call the Encrypt function?

Comment: I want to save connection string dynamically like this:         <connectionStrings>
  <add name="cn" connectionString="Mgye6RzGcs8gV04QGylkMkdOewkdx+J/YILu0hIv4QMQYtzCHRyIEyAMgN6hIJsC1lKy4yxNFAO+ri0Yf4iyyb3p5nmXixTo" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>

Comment: I dont get it... You encrypt the password on text changed? and then try to use it to open a connection?  To open the connection you need the clear unencrypted text for all connection string fields including the password.

Comment: Dear @Darkonekt Above encrypted connection string is working. How it working without decrypt clear text?

Comment: you have connection string encrypted in the config, ok. But what error do you have when trying to connect the db? You are using the custom encryption module so you have to decrypt the connection string manually when reading it from the config file. Another option is to use [SectionInformation.ProtectSection method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.sectioninformation.protectsection?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: How to decrypt connection string? Please give me sample code or project.

Answer (score 0):

Although you are using known cryptographic functions, you should rely on built in mechanisms that encrypt your connection string through configuration instead of coding it yourself. The reason being that you will have to store the decryption key somewhere safe.

For example IIS provides support for this.
Read here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/connection-string-encryption-and-decryption/ba-p/830094

Moreover, if you encrypt anything with an embedded key within your exe, minutes will be sufficient to decompile your application and extract the key. As such, you should use Windows Integrated Authentication instead of SQL Server Authentication.

Comment: He's not rolling his own encryption. In his code he is clearly using TripleDES with MD5. Actually read questions before answering them. You don't have to recompile to pick up a change in config.

Comment: @Josh I do not claim he does his own encryption although the wording might have lead to that conclusion. The rest of the answer clarify things up. Fixed my answer to clarify my point of view.

Answer (score -1):

I use a class to encrypt my connection string and i successfully encrypted my connection string. But i could not decrypted the encrypted when connect db. My class name is  EncryptPass and code is

```html
public static string EncryptPassword(string password)
        {
             //Using MD5 to encrypt a string
            using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
                //Hash data
                byte[] data = md5.ComputeHash(utf8.GetBytes(password));
                return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
            }
        }
    }
```

My encrypted connection string code is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="con"
       connectionString="JEXBqoI4UL2QA3IClyVMOA=="
       providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="True">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

I Use this following code to decrypt but not work.

```html
con = new OleDbConnection(EncryptPass.EncryptPassword(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString));
```

Its shows an error
[image]

Comment: well, decryption is opposite to encryption. You can't use the same `EncryptPass.EncryptPassword` to encrypt and decrypt data . Please check [the sample how to decrypt and encrypt data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413576/how-to-implement-triple-des-in-c-sharp-complete-example).